# JasperReport setting parameters

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports

I have some problems with JasperReport. I've generated a *.jrxml File through iReport. 
There I've definded some fields. Now i want to set these fields in my Java-Application, but it didn't work.

My Code looks like

```
JasperReport report;
    JasperPrint print;

    HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    parameters.put("logoPath", "\\logo.jpg");
    parameters.put("companyName", "Company Name");

    try {
        report = JasperCompileManager
                .compileReport("JRXML\\Template.jrxml");

        for (JRField field : report.getFields()) {
            System.out.println(field.getName() + "|"
                    + field.getValueClassName());
        }

        print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters,
                new JREmptyDataSource());
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,
                "\\temp\\Example.pdf");

        JasperViewer.viewReport(print);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Logger.getLogger(Example1.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL,
                e.getLocalizedMessage());

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The fields are given in the *.jrxml file.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you talking about fields or parameters? I see that you are only printing out the fields, never setting them..

Comment: In the .jrxml file i've defined fields with the names logoPath and companyName. And the tutorial i've read they said i could set the fields with a HashMap where the key is the field name. Thougt i would set the parameters with the method fillReport()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing parameters with fields. A paramater is defined as `<parameter name="companyName" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">`, while a field is defined as `<field name="companyName" class="java.lang.String"/>`. Convert company name to parameter in your jrxml and it should work.

From [this](http://fecplanner.com/jasperreports/docs/tutorial/index.html) tutorial

> **Parameters**
>
> Parameters are object references that are passed-in to the report
>   filling operations.     They are very useful for passing to the report
>   engine data that it can not normally find in its data source.
>
> **Fields**
>
> Report fields represent the only way to map data from the data source
>   into the report generating routines. When the data source of the
>   report is a ResultSet, all fields must map to corresponding columns in
>   the ResultSet object. That is, they must have the same name as the
>   columns they map and a compatible type.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Use a FileResolver for logo.jpg, which Jasper will use to resolve files locations.

```
FileResolver fileResolver = new FileResolver() {
@Override
public File resolveFile(String fileName) {
 URI uri = null;
 try {
uri = new URI(this.getClass().getResource("/" + fileName).getPath());
 } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
 }
return new File(uri.getPath());
}
};

HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

parameters.put("logoPath", "\\logo.jpg");
parameters.put("companyName", "Company Name");
parameters.put("REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER", fileResolver);
...
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters,
new JREmptyDataSource());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but didn't solve the problem. In the pdf-File all fields are displayed as null.

Comment: ok i'd suggest just comment out the part about logo.jpg from both java code and jrxml, then run it, if "Company Name" appears, then it's a file resolver issue else something is wrong with parameters.

Comment: I've commented out the field logoPath in the xml and java application but the value of companyName is still null.

Comment: it's given in the xml file as                             <textField>
    <reportElement uuid="a7f4feb4-8c12-46cb-9584-825557c31d77" x="118" y="0" width="337" height="54"/>
    <textElement markup="none"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{companyName}.toString()]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>

Comment: what is the parameter class defined for logoPath and companyName in the jrxml?

Comment: <field name="companyName" class="java.lang.String">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Company Name is displayed in the header]]></fieldDescription>
 </field> this is my field definition
 <!--
 <field name="logoPath" class="java.lang.String">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Path for the logo image]]></fieldDescription>
 </field>

Comment: ok you are confusing parameters with fields. A paramater is defined as <parameter name="companyName" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">, while a field is defined as <field name="companyName" class="java.lang.String"/>. Convert company name to parameter in your jrxml and it should work.

Comment: Yes that works, thank you very much. Could you explain for what fields are used? :)